Injectable in monorepo. Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type Class is not registered inside GetIt. Only for certain package
I have monorepo.
lib/
   main.dart

packages/
    dashboard/
    navigator/
        lib/src/domain/
             i_navigator.dart -> abstract class INavigator{...}
             nav.dart -> INavigator get nav => return getIt<INavigator>();
    practise/

Inside dashboard package I have button and onPressed method where I try to call nav.
onPressed() {
  print(getIt.hashCode);
  print(getIt.isRegistered<INavigator>());
  getIt<INavigator>().goNamed(...); <- This is fine.
  nav.goNamed(...); <- I get Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory... inside nav getter.

What's interesting if I move nav getter into dashboard package or any other package e.g. practise, getter works fine. The exception occurs only inside navigator package the same package where INavigator abstract class is defined.
Prints for onPressed method:
flutter: getIt.hashcode: 843783452
flutter: is INavigator registered: true

Prints for nav getter:
flutter: getIt.hashcode: 843783452
flutter: is INavigator registered: false

When I check with debugger, everything is registered inside getIt. Any ideas what could be wrong?
